# Make file_get_contents return only what i want

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have this code. And i want that in aray datte on every position to get a visit. but i get the results as strings. here is example:

"string(7652) "{"id":"34","nume":"STUDENT","bilet":null,"log":"2014-06-16 11:41:28\n2014-06-16 11:41:30\n2014-06-16 11:41:41\n2014-06-16 11:41:41\n2014-06-16 11:41:43\n2014-06-16 11:42:03\n2014-06-16 11:42:05\n2014-06-16 11:42:06\n2014-06-16 11:42:06\n2014-06-16 11:42:06\n2014-06-16 11:42:09\n2014-06-16 11:42:11\n2014-06-16 11:42: "

I need only the log...so i can make a heml table with that logs. Ideas?

```
public $datte = array();
public function aduDpServer(){
    $data = array ('foo' => 'bar', 'id' => 34); 
    $data = http_build_query($data); 
    $context_options = array ( 
        /*'http' => array ( 
            'method' => 'POST', 
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" 
            . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n", 
            'content' => $data 
        ) */
        'http'=> array(
            'method'=>'POST',
            'header'=>"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'content'=>$data
        )
    ); 
    $context = stream_context_create($context_options);
    $this->datte = file_get_contents('http://www.jajaja/x/updt.php', false, $context); 

    //var_dump($fp);

}

public function afiseaza(){
    //print_r($this->datte);
    echo"<table border=1 cellpading=0 cellspacing=0 >";
    echo"<th>Accesari</th>";
    $this->datte = is_array($this->datte) ? $this->datte: array($this->datte); //fortare vector
    foreach ($this->datte as $d) {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>".$d."</td>";echo"<br>";
        echo"</tr>";

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to loop over `$this->datte['log'];`

Comment: how? because i get all that string directly in my array datte.

Comment: It's a json string you need to decode it to  an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is a JSON, so you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert your data to php array.

```
$this->datte = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.jajaja/x/updt.php', false, $context), true);
```

Comment: not working... when i try to var_dump ($this->datte) i get NULL

Comment: Check if your data is a valid JSON. 
See example #3 : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: i used explode .. i see that i ask questions that i really don't know and i get -rep. It's very nice for the people who understand these to come here and instead of supporting us.. to give -. Thank you stackoverflow !